# C# print out ref string in method

Tags: c#

How can I achieve the following:

```
public void PrintText(ref string currentBid)
{
Console.WritleLine(currentBid);
}
```

Currently, I get the following error:

```
Cannot use ref or out parameter in annonymous method...
```

EDIT:

Here is the full method:

```
public static void writeToFileUK(string FolderName, ref string currentBid)
{
    TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(08, 00, 00);
    TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(16, 30, 00);

    var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
    {
        try
        {
            string fileName = @"C:\Users\Documents\Stocks\" + FolderName + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyy-MM-dd") + ".txt";
            if (!File.Exists(fileName))
                File.WriteAllText(fileName, "Time, Bid" + Environment.NewLine);

            string text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH-mm-ss") + ", " + currentBid;

            if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= start && DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay <= end)
            {
                using (StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(fileName, true))
                {
                    stream.WriteLine(text);
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }

    }, null, 0, 1000);

    Console.Read();
}


    try
    {
        Task.Run(() => writeToFileUK("HSBC", ref CurrentHSBCBid));
    }
    catch { }
```

This method will be called every second all day, and I want it to print the ref string to a text file

```
public override void OnUpdate(int itemPos, string itemName, IUpdateInfo update)
{
    try
    {
        var str = GetL1Prices(itemPos, itemName, update);
        var updateTime = update.GetNewValue("UPDATE_TIME");
        var bid = update.GetNewValue("BID");

        if(itemName == "L1:IX.D.DOW.DAILY.IP")
            Program.CurrentDOWBid = bid;
```

}
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }

Comment: Please post all your code. Furthermore, why do you need the `ref`?

Comment: Is there a reason for not having the method return the updated string? Would be an easier solution.

Comment: @JBKing becuase onOverride is not called directly by the code, but from what I understand, data is sent by lightstreamer and that calls the method, so I could not find a way of getting the value

Comment: What lightstreamer? That isn't in the code posted and thus how are we supposed to know about that part of your problem? Please give us enough context to give meaningful answers.

Answer (score 6):

Don't pass the string by reference.  You're not mutating the variable, so there's no reason to pass it by reference.  When you pass it by value (the default behavior) then you won't have any problems using it in an anonymous method, which doesn't support calling methods with `ref` parameters.

Comment: I am mutating it, that was just a snippet. I have posted the full code now

Comment: @user4420358 You are not mutating it in that snippet either.  You're only reading its value.  Of course, if you *wanted* to mutate it then you couldn't, just as the error message you have is telling you.  You can't pass a closed over variable by reference.

Comment: The value will be changed by lightstreamer and will be picked up along the way, but please answer the question I am asking, rather than telling me what my code does and does not do. I know what I am trying to acheive

Comment: @user4420358 Again, you're not actually mutating it, and again, you can't, even if you wanted to, for the exact reason stated in the error message you're getting.

Comment: @user4420358 I *did* answer your question.  You can make the code that you have function by not passing the variable by reference.

Comment: I have amethod which is called multiple times, and needs to print out one of the variable passed in. The variable that is passed in will change every second. Short of making 10 identical methods, I think I need to find a way to make it pint out the reference string that is passed in. No?

Comment: Well @user4420358 what part of _"**Cannot** use ref or out parameter inside an anonymous method body"_ don't you understand? Explain why you think you need that, and ask for an alternative...

Comment: @CodeCaster I need a way to pass a variable into a method, then when its value changes outside the method, the value inside the method needs to update to the new value,. It then needs to print out the current value of the variable. Isnt this what a reference string would do?

Comment: @user4420358 perhaps you need to do a msdn google search on the key word ref and what it mean and how it works in regards to scope have you thought about using `properties` instead..?

Comment: @user4420358 why not pass a class into your anonymous method which exposes the current string as a property or something?  Passing ref strings around is not possible in this context and even if it was, it wouldn't be a good idea - passing mutable resources around that the consumer doesn't own breaks encapsulation in a very bad way.

Comment: @TheInnerLight thank you for your answer. If you put that as an answer I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 2):

Passing a reference string into your anonymous method is not possible, instead pass in a class which maintains ownership of the string you wish to be regularly updated.

```
class BidUpdater
{
    private string _currentBid;
    public string CurrentBid { get { return currentBid; } }

    private void updateBid() 
    {
        /* update logic goes here */;
    }
}
```

then

```
Task.Run(() => writeToFileUK("HSBC", myBidUpdater));
```

where myBidUpdater is an instance of `BidUpdater`.

and then replace your usage of the result with

```
string text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH-mm-ss") + ", " + myBidUpdater.CurrentBid;
```

This is also preferable to passing by reference because the object responsible for updating the bid does not give up control over it (breaking encapulation).